# NGINX and routing between local server and a vm

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

i'm trying to make a decision, but i'm unsure if i can do the following with NGINX :

NGINX will be installed on a linux server that will have a windows VM on it

can NGINX point a fixed set of domains to the local Apache and reverse proxy everything else to/from the windows VM. As i know only the fixed set of domains that will be hosted on the Apache and the windows VM can have any number of unknown domains hosted on it.

Can this even work ? Can i use some sort of DB(mysql,postgre,mongo,redis,couchbase,memcached?) from where nginx can get the list of domains and to where to route them ?

Is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done with a wildcard server name: one server block for the fixed set of domains with a ReverseProxy directive to the local Apache server and another server block with a catch-all domain for the VM.

This can also be done with HAProxy using ACLs and user_backend for your fixed set of domains and default_backend else.